# How to specify username for SSH in Juniper router?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, ssh, cli

Model: ACX2200
Version : 15.1X54-D10.5

1. I have two Juniper routers connected back-to-back , first router is enabled     with TACACS login.
2. Second router is not enabled with TACACS login yet.
3. So to login to second router i need to use local username and password.
4. When i login to first router using TACACS credentials and then  try to login to second router from first router , it prompts password field directly without giving username prompt, hence mismatching TACACS username vs local password in second router.
5. It is taking username of first router , but i need to force it to use local username.

   In Cisco we have options for SHH to specify username { -l }.

[image: Juniper Possible SSH completion]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason the Juniper documentation (http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos13.2/topics/reference/command-summary/ssh.html) doesn't mention it, but it is possible. The command is:

```
ssh <username>@<hostname>
```

Comment: Great it worked . And do you have any idea why Cisco and juniper provide some different set of options for SSH even though SSH is open standard protocol.

Comment: The protocol is standard, but implementation can be different of course. JunOS is originally based on FreeBSD, so I'd assume that Juniper just took the FreeBSD implementation of ssh rather than writing their own code. The username@hostname syntax is pretty much standard in the Unix/Linux world. Cisco probably wrote their own implementation (or took the code from a different source).